# Japanese mathematics textbooks past grade 9

Tags: education

I cam across a list of mathematics textbooks used in japanese schools http://mathforum.org/kb/servlet/JiveServlet/download/206-2579263-9150698-840231/MathInternational0313_s%20GER.pdf

Are there japanese maths textbooks written in English past grade 9 all the way to university that are used in japan but are written in English?.

Thanks.

Comment: The University of Chicago School Mathematics Project did [translations](http://ucsmp.uchicago.edu/resources/translations/) of Japanese textbooks for grades 7 - 11, which you can order through the linked website.  The books for grades 10 and  11 are also available through [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=Kunihiko+Kodaira&ref=nb_sb_noss_2).

Comment: Thanks @N.F.Taussig i shall visit the project.